# Not able to declare a dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am getting compilation error for the following code. I have tried my best, but cannot figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 100

int counter=0;
struct node {
    int value; };
struct node *p = (struct node  *) malloc (N*sizeof (node));

void main()
{

    int a = 5, b=6;
        struct node * c = 0;
    c = add(a,b); 
}

void add(int m, int n)
{
    struct node * pin_1;
        struct node * pin_2;
        struct node * pin_0;
    pin_0->value = m;
    pin_1->value = n;
    pin_2->value = m + n;
    counter++;
    printf("value of out is %d /n", pin_2->value);       
}
```

I am getting the error in GCC:

> `struct_check.c:9:` error: `‘node’` undeclared here (not in a function)

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `c = add(a,b);` : `add` return type is `void`. `pin_1`, `pin_2` and `pin_0` are not initialized. (There is no need to use the pointer.)

Comment: and move malloc inside a function.

Comment: or `struct node *p = (struct node  *) malloc (N*sizeof (node));` -->  `struct node p[N];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, syntactically, you need to change

```
  struct node *p = (struct node  *) malloc (N*sizeof (node));
```

to

```
  struct node *p = malloc (N*sizeof ( struct node));
```

because, `node` itself is not a *type*, unless you use a `typedef` to create one.

That said,

- You cannot have a *statement to be executed* in global scope, move that inside some function.
- You never seem to make use of `p`, anywhere.
- You're using `pin_2` and `pin_0` uninitialized, that invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to make those pointers point to some valid memory before you can dereference them.
- `void main()` is obsolete as per the latest standard, and for a hosted environment, the conforming signature will be `int main(void)`, at aleast.
- You can write a more robust statement by using the style `struct node *p = malloc ( N *sizeof(*p));`

Comment: but then how do I typecast it to type node, if I dont use (struct node *) before malloc, without using typedef

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji You don;t, it's not needed, atleast in C.

Comment: Yes, the casting is mandatory in C++, but in C `void *` is implicitly casted to any `sometypename *`.

Comment: In C++, use of `malloc()` is discouraged.  By responding to such discouragement, i.e. not using `malloc()` in cases like this, the need for casting is avoided anyway.

Comment: My intention is to add two new array elements of type struct node(pin_0 and pin_1) and initialize them inside the add function. I am not able to figure out how to do that i.e my first element of array p should be pin_0 and should have a value of a and so on. I dont want to keep track of indices.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I got my expected results.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh My only question is that I am using struct node *p = malloc ( N *sizeof(*p)); which has restricted my use of node *p values inside the functions and only. I cannot get the values in my main function. Also, when I use another function say multiply, do I again write struct node *p = malloc ( N *sizeof(*p)); sinde that function and assign struct node * pin_0 = &p[index++] ?? I want my memory allocation to be accessed by main and all other functions, maybe keep it global and yet use it to allocate memory inside add, multiply functions.

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji allocate `p` in `main()` and pass it to function as argumnets.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I hate to ask this, but can you please provide a code script of the function , how to pass the p in function argument. I am not getting.

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji No offense, if that is the case, you need to read a C book. no SO question (or answer, for that matter) will be able to help you, that's simply too broad.

Comment: I got the answer. I was missing the &p[0] and instead giving p[0] as function arg